# Can I manually power down a USB hard drive in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Our backup script mounts an USB hard drive, copies some files, then unmounts. So, since the drive is only in use during this period, I thought it would be good to power down the drive once the backup is complete. Is there a command to do this? If yes, would I need to manually power it back up again when I need to use it next time?

Comment: What type of USB drive?  I know most of the Western Digital Mybooks will spin down the drive after inactivity.  Some of the better USB docks do this as well.

Comment: It's just a generic drive "toaster".

Comment: Just an update, I managed to get the drive to stop briefly by running `sg_start --stop /dev/sdc` but unfortunately the damn thing just starts it's self back up again!

Comment: Do you have HAL or udisks on your system?  If so, it may be a polling daemon that is waking it back up again.  If so, `hal-disable-polling --device /dev/sdc` or `udisks --inhibit-polling /dev/sdc` may help.

Comment: If your usb drive has has a plug for its electricity, you could plug that in a time switch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_switch). Then you could program the time switch to turn itself off and on at the times you choose.

Comment: ephemient: Nice suggestion, but I didn't have either `powertop` or `udisks` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://raw.github.com/liyan/suspend-usb-device/master/suspend-usb-device) script.

This script is designed to properly put an USB device into suspend
mode that can then be unplugged safely. But the ultimate effect is what you want to achieve.

Find some discussion about the similar topic [here](http://elliotli.blogspot.com/2009/01/safely-remove-usb-hard-drive-in-linux.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a USB hard drive that manages power anywhere other than a power switch or the cord itself.

If it were a NAS it may be possible to send commands to the underlying OS to shut it down (or suspend) and possibly send it WakeOnLan commands.

Comment: Are you sure `hdparm` won't help? Or maybe `sg_start`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking @nbolton?  Are you asking if I've tried them, or if I know how to bend those apps to do what you're trying to do, or something else?

Comment: if you've tried them id guess, i thought hdparm could do this myself.

Comment: I've successfully set the spin down time of a wd usb drive with hdparm and now it stops when I'm not using it.